# Can air-superiority radar function as weather radar?

Tags: military, weather, radar

Can the big, fat, sophisticated air-superiority radar in a modern fighter aircraft's nose serve as a weather radar for navigation in stormy conditions?

Alternatively would a datalink from somebody else (perhaps a tanker assigned to the deployment flight) be used to provide weather radar imagery into the cockpit?

Comment: It is possible that fire control radars do have weather modes built into the LRUs; I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @CarloFelicione -- it wouldn't surprise me if they did as it's sort of an obvious function to add (if you're a pilot that is ;) but I don't know either :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modern airborne fire-control radars have a weather mode. Examples include: [GRIFO-346](https://www.leonardocompany.com/documents/20142/3149717/GRIFO+M346+%28mm07796%29+HQ.pdf), [VixEn 1000E](https://www.leonardocompany.com/documents/20142/3149861/Vixen+1000E+-+Electronically+Scanned+AESA+Radar+%28mm08133%29+HQ.pdf), and [ELM-2032](https://www.iai.co.il/drupal/sites/default/files/2020-02/ELM-2032-Multimode%20Airborne%20Fire%20Control%20Radar%20Brochure.pdf) (brochure PDF links).

[This site](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323205230/http://www.vectorsite.net/ttradar_4.html) on Modern Radar Technology mentions the weather observation capability in modern combat planes:

> Digital capabilities allow a radar to change its functionality at will, resulting in the modern "multimode radars" carried by combat aircraft. A multimode radar might provide modes for: [...]
>
> - Weather observation. [...]

Comment: Yes this is true. The radar needs to be capable of tuning its pulse width or wavelength to pick up an object the size of a rain drop and then switch back to larger wavelengths in the X band of the radio frequency spectrum to pick up larger objects like other planes.